# Find and rm command deleted the files inside the directory and the directory itself

Tags: linux, files, find, directory, rm

Can you please check this command? It's deleting the files and the current directory itself. Script is run via cron.

Directories:

```
/log/dir/
/log/dir/tmp/
```

Commands in script:

```
find /log/dir/ -mtime +7 -name "*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
find /log/dir/tmp -mtime +7 -name "*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Testing:
Run the `find /log/dir/ -mtime +7 -name "*"` to check the files and I got result. After running the script, the file was deleted. After some days, the folders got deleted as well (the dir in `/log/dir/` and the tmp in `/log/dir/tmp`).

Expectation should be only the files/directories INSIDE the path provided older than 7 days will be deleted.

Linux redhat6.5

Comment: add '-mindepth 1' and remove -name "*"

Comment: find /log/dir/ -mtime +7 -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} \; --- like this?

Comment: yes... '-mindepth 1' ensures not-deleting main directory, not mentioned bellow, but '-type f' will also disallow it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `find` to delete only regular files and no directories, then make absolutely sure that you use `-type f`.  This will prevent pathnames that refer to directories (or anything that is not a regular file) to be processed.  The directories got deleted since their last modified timestamp fulfilled the criteria for deletion.

Also, if you are deleting files, don't use `rm -r` since recursing into a regular file does not make sense.  With most `find` implementations you can also choose to use `-delete` rather than `-exec rm`.

The `-name "*"` is a no-op and could be removed since *every* name matches `*`.

If you run find over `/log/dir`, then you don't need to run it on `/log/dir/tmp` as the latter will be processed as part of the former.  If you intend to only look in these two directories, but not in subdirectories, add `-maxdepth 1` to `find` (if it supports it), and in that case, you *do* need to process them separately (but this may be done in one `find` invocation as the utility takes any number of top-directories).

Suggestion, depending on what it is you want to achieve:

```
find /log/dir /log/dir/tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +7 -delete
```

---

The `mtime` of a directory is updated when a file is added or deleted from the directory. It is therefore unclear whether your attempts to delete *directories* based on the last modified timestamp is a good idea to start with.

---

For rotation of log files, you may also look into using `logrotate` or some similar utility, from a cron job.

Comment: Yes, it turned out that it deleted the directory itself because it fits the criteria of being older than 7days.

Let's say the two directories are different: /log/dir and /otherdir/tmp 
Can I still include it in one line such as 

find /log/dir /otherdir/tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +7 -delete

Will that be okay?

Comment: @chelseagirl01 That command will look for regular files that have a modification timestamp of more than a week ago and delete them. It will look inside the two directories `/log/dir` and `/otherdir/tmp`, but not in their subdirectories.  If that's what you want, then it will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what you mean by 'older than 7 days'. Could be accessed more than 7 days ago, changed more than 7 days ago or created more than 7 days ago. All different situations. Also are you sure you want to consider files *and* directories?

If you are looking to delete files and directories, then the 2nd command is redundant, since `/log/dir/tmp` would be listed under `/log/dir`.

Using `-r` on rm is careless in this situation and will probably delete more than what you want to. Find is already listing all files/directories recursively so you are jumping ahead of find's output by deleting recursively. Stick to `rm -f` and let find list the files to delete.

What I think you are trying to do is simply:
    find /log/dir/ -type f -ctime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;